# Tomcat Basic Authentication Permissions Issue

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, jersey

I currently have a web service running some basic authentication through Tomcat. I get the login box to pop up fine, and I can log in with accounts I have defined in the tomcat-users.xml file.  However, when it comes to defining permissions based on roles, I'm having some issues.

Currently, I have three roles: manager, admin, and user.  I have a few methods which should be only accessible by, say, an admin role.  I can log in as my manager/admin/user super account and see everything just fine- but I can do the same as a normal user as well.

The methods are defined like so:

```
@Path("/Test")
@RolesAllowed("admin")
public class Test
{
    @GET
    @RolesAllowed("user")
    public methodThatMyUsersCanAcess{}

    @GET
    @Path("/Secure")
    @RolesAllowed("admin")
    public methodThatOnlyAdminsCanAcess{}
}
```

I'm really not sure how a 'user' role would be able to access the second method, but somehow it still happens.

Comment: So just to be clear, it looks like the `/Test` resource maps to `methodTheMyUsersCanAccess` and should only be accessible by the `user` role and `/Test/Secure` maps to `methodThatOnlyAdminsCanAccess` and is only accessible by the `admin` role. The `@RolesAllowed` annotation is from JSR 250 which states that its use in a method should override its use at the class level. What happens when you remove the `@RolesAllowed` annotation from the class level?

Comment: It's still doing the same thing.  Logged in as a 'user', I'm still able to access the 'admin' method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more investigation, I discovered that using `@RolesAllowed` was doing nothing in my code due to the way my web.xml file was configured.  I decided to move in the direction of setting authentication by URI path.  This is done through modifying the web.xml to allow a subset of users to access each path under separate `<security-constraint>` tags.  I found my best resource for this here: http://www.coderanch.com/t/176095/java-Web-Component-SCWCD/certification/auth-constraint-confusion in the second post.

Answer (score 0):

The key point is to configure `RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory` in web.xml, as below:

```
<servlet> 
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class> 
        <init-param> 
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name> 
            <param-value>com.mycompany.mobile.rest</param-value> 
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Trace</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.mycompany.mobile.rest.filter.RestSecurityFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
</servlet>
```